# Efficiently Filtering One DataTable matching multiple columns of another DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, datatable

I have two DataTable's and I have a function to filter matching records. Following is my function:

```cs
public static DataTable FilterCandidates(DataTable FullCandidateData, DataTable RequiredCandidateIDs)
{
    DataTable ReqCandidateData = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        var MacthingIDs = FullCandidateData.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Candidate_ID")).Intersect(RequiredCandidateIDs.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Candidate_ID")));

        ReqCandidateData = (from row in FullCandidateData.AsEnumerable()
                            join Candidate_ID in MacthingIDs
                            on row.Field<string>("Candidate_ID") equals Candidate_ID
                            select row).CopyToDataTable();
        return ReqCandidateData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ReqCandidateData = FullCandidateData.Clone();
        return ReqCandidateData;
    }
}
```

Is there any other efficient way of doing this, Somehow I am not comfortable in assuming that exception is equivalent to **No matching records**. Also I can do that by finding the length, but it will increase the no.of loops drastically, I have around 90,000 candidates in my First DataTable and it keeps growing.

Also please let me know how can I do this if I have multiple column comparison, like **Candidate_ID** and **Job_ID**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single join to server your purpose. The first function below matches only Candidate_ID and second function matches both Candidate and job id. Refer to third method to get all the rows from "FullCandidateData" that do not match "RequiredCandidateIDs"

```
public static System.Data.DataTable FilterCandidates(System.Data.DataTable FullCandidateData, System.Data.DataTable RequiredCandidateIDs)
{
    System.Data.DataTable reqCandidateData = new System.Data.DataTable();
    try
    {
        var reqCandidateDt = (from candidateRow in FullCandidateData.AsEnumerable()
                              join reqCandidateRow in RequiredCandidateIDs.AsEnumerable()
                              on candidateRow["Candidate_ID"].ToString() equals reqCandidateRow["Candidate_ID"].ToString()
                              select candidateRow);

        if (reqCandidateDt.Count() > 0)
        {
            reqCandidateData = reqCandidateDt.CopyToDataTable();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return reqCandidateData;
}




public static System.Data.DataTable FilterCandidates(System.Data.DataTable FullCandidateData, System.Data.DataTable RequiredCandidateIDs)
{
    System.Data.DataTable reqCandidateData = new System.Data.DataTable();
    try
    {
        var reqCandidateDt = (from candidateRow in FullCandidateData.AsEnumerable()
                              join reqCandidateRow in RequiredCandidateIDs.AsEnumerable()
                              on
                              new { CandidateId = candidateRow["Candidate_ID"].ToString(), Job_Id = candidateRow["Job_ID"].ToString() }
                              equals
                              new { CandidateId = reqCandidateRow["Candidate_ID"].ToString(), Job_Id = reqCandidateRow["Job_Id"].ToString() }
                              select candidateRow);

        if (reqCandidateDt.Count() > 0)
        {
            reqCandidateData = reqCandidateDt.CopyToDataTable();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return reqCandidateData;
}

public static System.Data.DataTable FilterCandidates(System.Data.DataTable FullCandidateData, System.Data.DataTable RequiredCandidateIDs)
{
    System.Data.DataTable reqCandidateData = new System.Data.DataTable();
    try
    {
        var reqCandIds = RequiredCandidateIDs.AsEnumerable().Select(reqCandidateRow => reqCandidateRow["Candidate_ID"].ToString());
        var reqCandidateDt = (from candidateRow in FullCandidateData.AsEnumerable()
                              where !reqCandIds.Contains(candidateRow["Candidate_ID"].ToString())
                              select candidateRow);

        if (reqCandidateDt.Count() > 0)
        {
            reqCandidateData = reqCandidateDt.CopyToDataTable();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return reqCandidateData;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much, I think when there are no matching records, .CopyToDataTable(); throws an exception.

Comment: you have ~6k reputation, yet your code formatting is a mess.

Comment: Hi @AksheyBhat, If I want to get all the rows from "FullCandidateData" that do not match "RequiredCandidateIDs", what should I do, I saw many threads, but all of them are using Field type, I want to do that without using Field Type.

Comment: @PrasanthKumarVinakota Refer to third method to get all the rows from "FullCandidateData" that do not match "RequiredCandidateIDs" without using field type

Answer (score 0):

**I have around 90,000 candidates in my First Datatable and it keeps growing.**

With respect to this, you would probably need to start designing/thinking about the load.

I would suggest:

1. Filter data before it comes into datatable on basis of date - give user facility to search data from Archive table
2. Yes, choose right and multiple key to filter out data. Filter sequence also matters in this case.
3. Keep target of keeping count of data in control limit or else you will end in Performance issues
4. For filtering large dataset, you can think to take it to database side, it will be more efficient and fast.